# Incompatible block pointer types in helper class

Tags: ios

I have a unusual error. My application was running however when I opened it this morning I get a

`Incompatible block pointer types assigning to 'void(^_strong)(NSString*_strong)' from 'void(^_strong)(NSString *_strong, int'`

This is the code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^completionHandler)(NSString *, NSInteger);

-(void)showInView:(UIView *)view withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *, int))handler{
    _completionHandler = handler;

    [_actionSheet showInView:view];
}
```

Not sure what to do. It is a helper class so not my code.

Comment: Try deleting the code and retyping it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Type **int** to **NSInterger**  in the method definition, it works

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^completionHandler)(NSString *, NSInteger);

-(void)showInView:(UIView *)view withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *,  NSInteger))handler{

            _completionHandler = handler;
            [_actionSheet showInView:view];
        }
```